# Merging bulk data in 10.2 ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, merge

I have to merge 50 datasets. All datasets have same feature classes. please suggest me fastest way. append, merge, load, all methods will take time. please suggest me fastest way.

Comment: With Merge you can easily combine a number of datasets. What is the time critical part, data processing? Are you asking for the fastest algorithm?

Comment: Are you familiar with batch processing? See: http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00210000000w000000

Answer (score 1):

If all spatial references are the same, build a few models to append a few of the feature classes at a time.  Make another model that runs the smaller models.  Run the model overnight.  I've had terrible luck running into memory issues with large data loads operations, this method works best for me.